# How to handle missing invoked method

Tags: c#, asynchronous

```
public void RefreshData()
{
    // this is called on UI thread

    List<ds> dataSource;
    GetDsDelegate caller = GetDs;
    caller.BeginInvoke(out dataSource, RefreshCallback, null);
}

private void RefreshCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    // this is called on worker thread

    try
    {
        var result = (AsyncResult)ar;
        var caller = (GetDsDelegate)result.AsyncDelegate;

        List<ds> dataSource;
        var success = caller.EndInvoke(out dataSource, ar);

        if (success)
        {
            BeginInvoke(new Action<List<ds>>(SetGridDataSource), dataSource);
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        // NOTE: It's possible for this form to close after RefreshData is called
        // but before GetDs returns thus the SetGridDataSource method no longer exists.
        // Not catching this error causes the entire application to terminate.
    }

private void SetGridDataSource(List<ds> dataSource)
{
    // this is called on UI thread
    dataGrid.DataSource = dataSource;
}
```

RefreshData, RefreshCallback, and SetGridDataSource are all methods of a windows Form class.  Calling RefreshData invokes the external method GetDs using the GetDsDelegate delegate.  When GetDs completes, it calls RefreshCallback (now on a separate thread).  Finally, SetGridDataSource is invoked to complete the update.

All this works fine unless GetDs is delayed and the form closes.  Then when GetDs completes and calls RefreshCallback, SetGridDataSource no longer exists.

Is there a better way of handling this condition other then the shown try/catch block?  I’d prefer to prevent the error rather than ignore it.  Is there a better pattern to use?

**EDIT**

As I look that the error, it’s obvious to change `if (success)` to `if (success && IsHandleCreated)` to prevent it, but it still seems like I’m doing something wrong, or at least awkward.  I could also replace the second BeginInvoke with just Invoke so EndInvoke is unnecessary.  I like the idea of moving the logic away from the form, but I don't see how the result would change.  I would think a BackgroundWorker would also have the same issue; that being the callback is no longer accessible.  I suppose an event could be raised with the result, but that seems a little abstract.  Could you please elaborate a little more or provide an example.

Comment: This is an unsolvable race condition, you cannot allow the form to close until all worker threads have completed running.  This is a lot easier to accomplish with BackgroundWorker.

Answer (score 0):

The method does exist. The fact the form was closed does not change the class or its methods. If you post the exact exception you're getting, it can help someone offer a more accurate help.

I'm guessing you got an `ObjectDisposedException` when you tried to do something on the form or one of its control after it has been closed.

If that's the case you just have to enhance your logic and check if the form has been closed or disposed before calling SetGridDataSource.

That said, there seem to be some issues with your design.

1. You're calling SetGridDataSource from the thread pool, but it probably should called from the UI thread.
2. Your'e not chaining the asynchronous calls correctly. And specifically, you're not calling `EndInvoke` on the second `BeginInvoke`.
3. A nice way that can help you get the threading right is to use something like the `BackgroundWorker` instead of chaining `BeginInvoke` calls.
4. Consider moving the business logic (including the threading and asynchronity logic) away from the UI layer and the form.
5. It's a very bad idea to do a `catch` without an exception type, and handle any thrown exception by ignoring it without rethrowing.

By the way, instead of doing this:

```
BeginInvoke(new Action<List<ds>>(SetGridDataSource), dataSource);
```

you can do the following, which I think is more readable:

```
BeginInvoke(SetGridDataSource, dataSource);
```

Comment: Does .NET 4 compiler support that last inference example? I am pretty sure it doesn't work in .NET 3.5.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Invoking SetGridDataSource produces an "Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created." exception.  This makes sense to me given the form has been closed.